# How to extend my facebook access_token with Python?

Tags: python, facebook

I already have an access_token but it's a short_lived_token. For my application I need a long_lived_token, and I know how to get it in java, but I'm using Python.

Does anybody know how to get a long_lived access_token in python? Or how to update my short_lived to a long_lived in python?

Comment: If you want to know how to do in python then why have you written in question via Graph explorer?

Comment: My current access_token I got from graph explorer.

Comment: Okay, but could you change the title of your question cause it seems a little different than to your main problem which is about extending access token in python. Also, are you using Facebook's python SDK?

Comment: Is this question a little bit better? and yes I am using the facebook's python SDK. Everything works with this access_token, the only problem is when I really start using my application I'm not going to update the access_token every 2 hours, so I need the long_lived one, but how I can extend it with python is not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a method `extend_access_token` defined in the [Python SDK](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk/blob/master/facebook.py#L377) which would, as per internal documentation

> Extends the expiration time of a valid OAuth access token.

Which would be the thing you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this. I don't have an application on facebook yet, so I should make that first.

Comment: Ok, it works, I can extend my acces_token. Only problem now is finding the good authorisation tools. I did enter the correct permissions, yet when I test it on my test users I get an error that I'm not authorised. But I have asked the same permissions as I did with the graph explorer. I guess it's just something that I do wrong in the facebook-app, feel like a noob now, guess I just have to try some other things. Thanks anyway, you helped a lot.

Comment: @Kyra , Could you also accept this as the answer if this answers your query

Comment: I'm not using an app. So what do I use for the app parameters?